# Salesforce introduction for Sales people

Tags: sales

I need to give an overview of the Salesforce platform to Sales people in my organization. What topics should I cover and are there any readily available guides?

Answer (score 3):

Trailhead has your back:

https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/trails/discover-sales-cloud

https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/trails/get-started-with-sales-cloud

You can take content from there, or even just run through the material with your sales team

Comment: Or may be this to start: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/trails/getting_started_crm_basics